# SQL Syntax Error with reserved words (Java)

Tags: java, mysql

I have problem with sql syntax error, my query and code looks like this:

---

```
@Override
public void insert() {
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = Main.getSQL().getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO `" + Settings.mysqlPref + "guilds` (name, tag, owner, allies, points, kills, deaths, validity, " +
                        "attacked, home, members, pvp, born, lives, bossHealth) " +
                        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setString(2, tag);
        stmt.setString(3, ownerUniqueId.toString());
        stmt.setString(4, Serializer.serializeList(allies));
        stmt.setInt(5, getPoints());
        stmt.setInt(6, kills);
        stmt.setInt(7, deaths);
        stmt.setLong(8, validity);
        stmt.setLong(9, protection);
        stmt.setString(10, Serializer.serializeLocation(home));
        stmt.setString(11, Serializer.serializeList(members));
        stmt.setBoolean(12, pvp);
        stmt.setLong(13, born);
        stmt.setInt(14, lives);
        stmt.setInt(15, bossHealth);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is a stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name', 'tag', 'owner', 'allies', 'points', 'kills', 'deaths', 'validity', 'atta' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    at me.khalit.prostorm.tools.data.Guild.insert(Guild.java:126)
    at me.khalit.prostorm.tools.util.thread.Work.execute(Work.java:71)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

The problem is - for me it works properly, but for my client (like you see above) it doesn't. I don't know what is the problem because for me everything works properly. On SQLite or MySQL, no difference.

I saw it can be a problem with reserved words in MySQL, but I did `'guilds'` and it should work properly. Unfortunatelly it doesn't for my client.

I just gave up, maybe you guys have some solutions? I don't know what code snippets you need, so tell me if any is required.

Comment: `''name'` looks suspicious for me. Maybe extra `'` break something?

Comment: What is `Settings.mysqlPref` ?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use a SQL-Query Builder like Jooq/Speedment.. Plain SQL in a Java application is a headache..

Comment: I think you did confuse some `'` with `\``, can we see the exact query as it is at the moment "I saw it can be a problem with reserved words in MySQL, but I did 'guilds'" makes me think the current query is not the one posted in your code

Comment: Is this the actual code as-is? Your code has `name, tag, owner`... while the error shows that MySQL got `'name', 'tag', 'owner'` with single quotes

Comment: Perhaps both you and your customer can print the SQL string (I mean something like:  String str="insert into...." , then System.out.print it, then prepareStatement(str)).  Could be that your customer has a different "pref", or that he managed to stick some space characters in there, etc...

Comment: @Galz yes, it is. I tried also with `'name', 'tag'`, same.
@RC It is query that i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

What is Settings.mysqlPref? If that is the database name, you can't have db_name.table_name wrapped in backticks. You either need to remove the backticks or put them around the db_name and aroudn the table_name. Make sense?

Comment: It is prefix for database, like `Prefix_MainTableName`.

Comment: @xVacuumis it possible that on your client's database the prefix includes the db name? like `my_db.Prefix_MainTableName`? If so, CptMisery is right. Try removing the backticks altogether. They are a headache anyway. And if you can, in the future, don't build SQL commands as Strings! It's a world of pain.